# Access relative files from a sandboxed iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I want to understand if the following scenario would work -
Assume, I the following setup of files

```
parent.html
style.css
logic.js
child.html
```

parent.html is as follows -

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="logic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, World</h1>
<iframe sandbox src="child.html">
</body>
</html>
```

Assume that child.html is

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="logic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, from Child Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Assume that parent.html is served and consumed like -
`example.com/parent.html`

My Question  is - will the relative paths accessed from child.html (logic.js & style.css files) work ? If so, why ?

I tried this setup locally ( just hosted a simple http server ) and things seems to work.

I was of the opinion that this wouldn't work given that child.html is loaded in a sandboxed iframe, which gets a unique origin and so, there is a no base URL to resolve the relative paths against.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

None of the restrictions imposed by [the `sandbox` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) restrict loading of resources into a document.

You can link to scripts and stylesheets freely.

> I was of the opinion that this wouldn't work given that child.html is loaded in a sandboxed iframe, which gets a unique origin and so, there is a no base URL to resolve the relative paths against.

Changing the origin doesn't change the base URL. It only affects things which pay attention to the Same Origin Policy. For example, if the script tried to `fetch('/').then(res => res.text())`  it would fail because the fetch API implements the Same Origin Policy. Likewise if you said `<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">` it would fail as the `crossorigin` attribute adds a dependency on the SOP.

Comment: Thanks for the details. is there some good links / docs on what exactly base-URL is ( especially, in context of iframe ) & how browser resolves the relative paths ? thanks.

Comment: The base URL is the URL of the HTML document you load in the frame. URLs work the same way as normal.